# How do i create a usercontrol that can search on a website

Tags: c#

i do like to create a usercontrol that can perform a search query on a website.

here's my working code:

```
public static void SearchGoogle(string GoogleQuery)
        {
            Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + YoutubeQuery);
        }

        private void GsearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchGoogle(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

as you can see when the user input a search query then my C# form will search that query. it works but when I tried to add it on a userControl with a different search engine like this one:

```
public static void SearchYoutube(string YoutubeQuery)
        {
            Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + YoutubeQuery);
        }

        private void GsearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchYoutube(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

it keeps sending me to google search query instead of youtube. how do I fix this?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your projects

Comment: Look at the click handlers they are the same except the code in it... You may want a youtube click handler.

Comment: whats a click handler?